# Extending Templates: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, templates, syntax-error

Getting several errors of type "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " when I load the same template with a different request.

My project url:

```
url(r'^$', 'larkspur.views.home', name='home'),     
url(r'^test/', 'larkspur.views.home', name='home'),
```

My app view:

```
def home(request):
return render_to_response('larkspur/index.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I load mysite.com/ everything loads fine. When I load mysite.com/test things get a little whacky First, I get several "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ". Additionally, some javascript doesn't seem to function correctly, though it appears to load fully.

Any guesses or help would be greatly appreciated. Possibly relevant code below:

index.html (modified from a purchased/licensed HTML5 template):

```
{% extends "larkspur/base.html" %} 

 {% block content %}
    <!-- CONTENT BEGIN -->
    <div id="content" class="">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="block_slider_type_1 general_not_loaded">
                <div id="slider" class="slider flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <li>
                            <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_slider_1_1.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_1" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown">Travel, PHOTOGRAPHY</div>
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_2" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown">Mountains in Switzerland</div>
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_3" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown"><a href="#" class="general_button_type_1">Read More</a></div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_slider_1_2.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_1" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown">Travel, PHOTOGRAPHY</div>
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_2" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown">My Love - New York</div>
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_3" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown"><a href="#" class="general_button_type_1">Read More</a></div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_slider_1_3.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_1" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown">Life, PHOTOGRAPHY</div>
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_2" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown">My Awesome workplace</div>
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_3" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown"><a href="#" class="general_button_type_1">Read More</a></div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_slider_1_4.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_1" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown">Life, PHOTOGRAPHY</div>
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_2" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown">Flying over the mountains</div>
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_3" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown"><a href="#" class="general_button_type_1">Read More</a></div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_slider_1_5.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_1" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown">People, Fashion</div>
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_2" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown">Young Businessman</div>
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_3" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown"><a href="#" class="general_button_type_1">Read More</a></div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_slider_1_6.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_1" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown">People, Life</div>
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_2" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown">The guy on the field</div>
                            <div class="animated_item text_1_3" data-animation-show="fadeInUp" data-animation-hide="fadeOutDown"><a href="#" class="general_button_type_1">Read More</a></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function() {
                        init_slider_1('#slider');
                    });
                </script>
            </div>

            <div class="block_general_title_1 w_margin_1">
                <h1>Latest Posts</h1>
                <h2>ENTER THE SUB TITLE FOR THIS SECTION</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="block_posts type_1 type_sort general_not_loaded">
                <div class="posts">
                    <article class="post_type_1">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_1.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><span>TOP NEWS.</span> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus sit volup.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_1">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_6.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html">Red ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_1">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_11.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html">Perspiciatis unde omnis iste.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_1">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_7.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html">Totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore verit.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_1">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_12.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><span>NEWS.</span> Totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_2">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_2.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html">Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_3">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html">Veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_2">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_13.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html">Accusantium doloremque lauda ntium, totam.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_2">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_3.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html">Enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_1">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_14.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus sit volup.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_2">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_8.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus sit volup.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_1">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="slider">
                                <div id="post_slider_1" class="flexslider">
                                    <ul class="slides">
                                        <li><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_4.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                        <li><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_16.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                        <li><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_17.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    jQuery(function() {
                                        init_post_slider_1('#post_slider_1');
                                    });
                                </script>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><span>TOP NEWS.</span> Quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_2">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_9.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html">Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_1">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post_video.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_10.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover no_icon"></span><span class="icon video"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post_video.html"><span>TOP NEWS.</span> Totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inven.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_2">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_15.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html">Totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_1">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href="blog_post_review.html"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}larkspur/images/pic_post_1_5.jpg" alt=""><span class="hover"></span></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="review">
                                <div class="num">7.5</div>
                                <div class="type">score</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post_review.html">Voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class="post_type_3">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="tags"><a href="#">TRAVEL</a>, <a href="#">LIFE</a></div>
                                <div class="date">27, 2013</div>
                                <div class="stats">
                                    <div class="likes">15</div>
                                    <div class="comments">7</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="title">
                                <a href="blog_post.html">Accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaqu.</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>

                <div class="controls">
                    <a href="#" id="button_load_more" data-target=".block_posts.type_sort .posts" class="load_more_1"><span>Load more posts</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CONTENT END -->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: And the contents of the home file with relevant code?

Comment: I think @karthikr means can you include ```larkspur/base.html```